# Latest document for each category?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have documents in ElasticSearch with structure like this:

```
{
    "created_on": [timestamp],
    "source_id": [a string ID for the source],
    "type": [a term],
    ... other fields
}
```

Obviously, I can select these documents in Kibana, show them in "discover", produce (for example) a pie chart showing type terms, and so on.

However, the requirement I've been given is to use only the most recent document for each `source_id`.

The approach I've tried is to map the documents into one bucket per `source_id`, then for each bucket, reduce to remove all but the document with the latest `created_on`.

However, when I used the `terms` aggregator, the result only contained counts, not whole documents I could further process:

```
"aggs" : {
    "sources" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "source_id" }
    }
}
```

How can I make this query?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, one way to accomplish that is using the ***[top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)*** aggregations under the **terms** aggregation, which is useful for grouping results by any criteria you'd like to, for each bucket of its parent aggregation. Following your example, you could do something like

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_source_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "source_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "most_recent": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": {
              "created_on": "desc"
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So you are grouping by source_id, which will create a bucket for each one, and then you'll get the top hits for each bucket according to the sorting criteria set in the top_hits agg, in this case the **created_on** field.

The result you should expect would be something like

```
....

"buckets": [
        {
          "key": 3,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "most_recent": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 2,
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "so_sample02",
                  "_type": "items",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "created_on": "2018-05-01 07:00:01",
                    "source_id": 3,
                    "type": "a"
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    1525158001000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 5,
          "doc_count": 2, .... and so on
```

Notice how within the bucket, **most_recent**, we get the corresponding hits. You can furthermore limit the amount of fields returned, by specifying in your **top_hits** agg `"includes": ["fieldA", "fieldB" .. and so on]`

Hope that helps.